# Why do the derivatives of a function lead towards the extremum of the function?

Tags: derivatives, optimization

Is there some theorem in mathematics that formalizes the idea that "for some function, at a given point, moving in the negative direction of the gradient leads you to some (local) extremum point"? For example, in the gradient descent algorithm, what exactly justifies the general directions we follow when searching for the optimum point?

Recently, I read about Fermat's Theorem on Stationary Points, which says that if the point (a,b) is a local extremum for some function f then the derivative of f at the point (a,b) is 0. Is there some extension of this theorem that states (the obvious idea) that moving in the negative direction of the gradient leads you to this (local) extremum point? Or is this idea so basic and intuitive that no proof is required?

Comment: In the text use $$ please, i.e.  $(a,b)$ instead of just (a,b), $0$ instead of just 0.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, there is a theorem proving that any $f\in\mathcal{C}^2$ with positive definite Hessian, for which the gradient descent method converges to some point, automatically converges (linearly) to the local minimum of $f$. The proof is for example in D.G.Luenberger, Y.Ye., *Linear and Nonlinear Programming*, 3.Auflage, Springer, 2008, Bd.116.